# How to get a specific set of characters from a string using cut (or not)

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, cut

I am trying to extract the PHP version from this command: php -v

```
php -v
PHP 7.3.27-9+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli) (built: Feb 23 2021 15:10:30) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.27, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.3.27-9+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies
```

By using cut I can get the data I need, however, cut also parses the other 3 lines, so I end with:

```
php -v | cut -c4-10

7.3.27
yright 
d Engin
with Z
```

Is there a way to tell cut to stop after the first line?
If not, what alternatives do I have?

Answer (score 2):

```
php -v | head -n1 | cut -c4-10
```

Answer (score 0):

```
php -v | sed -En '/^PHP/s/[^0-9]+(([0-9]+\.){2}[0-9]+)\-.+/\1/p'
```

This uses `sed` to select the line starting with `PHP` and then extracts the version number from that line.

Comment: You must love regex a lot!